# Excel copy worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba, copy, worksheet

In Excel VBA (or if you could in C#, I'm using the Excels Object Library from .NET), how to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another sheet in another workbook. Basically, what I'm doing is copying every of my sheet into a central worksheet in another workbook and then will do all the stuff I need to do there. I tried using Range.Copy method, I gave the Destination parameter as the range of the other workbook. It worked perfectly, but there is one problem, that is every time I copy it replaces the older data in that worksheet. How do I do something like so that when I paste it pastes in the end of the sheet.

**EDIT:** I searched and found a way, but now when I copy the cells I get a COM exception with the message *"To paste all cells from an Excel worksheet into the current worksheet, you must paste into the first cell (A1 or R1C1)."*

Following is the code, it is in C#

```
logWorksheet = logWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;

Excel.Range tempRange = logWorksheet.Cells[logWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A"] as Excel.Range;
tempRange = tempRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);

int emptyRow;

if (tempRange.Row > 1)
    emptyRow = tempRange.Row + 1;
else
    emptyRow = tempRange.Row;

string copyLocationAddress = Convert.ToString(emptyRow);

Excel.Range copyLocation = logWorksheet.get_Range(
                            "A" + copyLocationAddress, Type.Missing) as Excel.Range;

// copy whole workbook to the central workbook
tempLogSheet.Cells.Copy(copyLocation);
```

Comment: Worksheets have a finite size, so if you are copying whole worksheets, there is no room to "append" more than one to a single worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

-- UPDATE --

This snippet copies the cells A1:A3 of Book1 to Book2. It will find the last used cell in Book2 and will append the data underneath it.

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyRow As Long

Set source = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destination = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")

'find empty row (actually cell in Column A)'
emptyRow = destination.Cells(destination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If emptyRow > 1 Then
    emptyRow = emptyRow + 1
End If

source.Range("A1:A3").Copy destination.Cells(emptyRow, 1)

End Sub
```

-- OLD --

This sample copies all the sheets of Book1.xlsx to Book2.xlsx:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets.Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Indeed, it does. But I want to copy the sheet's content to another sheet which is in another workbook ;)

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify the title to be 'Excel copy worksheet content' instead of just worksheet ;)

Comment: Oops... that was a bug when trying to find the empty row when no data is yet available in Book2. It is fixed now.

Comment: If you are looking for the last used cell in the target sheet, you might want to check the built-in function which does that for you:
var lastCell = xlWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);