# VBA Copy Worksheet to a Different Open Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, worksheet

I keep getting an Out of Range error when trying to copy a sheet from on workbook to another.  The original spreadsheet (Master_Data.xlsm) is what is running the vba script.  The scripts opens another spreadsheet, manipulates it, then copies the final sheet to be pasted in the Master_Data.xlsm Workbook.

```
Sub Result_Scrapper()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wbFile As Object
Dim masterBook As Workbook
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim year As Integer


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Output_Spreadsheets\")
Set masterBook = Excel.Workbooks("Master_Data.xlsm")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files
If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsm" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
    'Copy sheet of interest
    ActiveSheet.Copy 'Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“A”) 'tried doing it using before statement but it also caused errors
    'paste sheet into masterBook spread--this is where the error comes
    masterBook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Paste

    End If
masterBook.Sheets("master").Name = Right([A2], 30)
Next wbFile
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel copy worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599715/excel-copy-worksheet)

Comment: @UriGoren bad target, that's C# code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. First, as someone else commented, you need to fully qualify the count. Second, you'll want to do it on one line; and you could do before, but then you're just pushing out whatever that last sheet is, if you add it after, then the sheets stay in order.

Try:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=masterBook.Sheets(masterBook.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Or, even better: `wb.worksheets("Specify the name here").Copy After:=masterBook.Sheets(masterBook.Sheets.Count)` since you've just opened the workbook `wb` and don't know what sheet in it may be active.

Comment: I agree, it would be better to get rid of the ActiveSheet, but that's a different issue than the original question and there wasn't enough info from the original post (i.e. the sheet name) to implement it.